# How to load external website in my view ASP.NET Core

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

I have a view in my ASP.NET Core application.The view split into 2 div containers Left and right containers in the 1st container i load some stuff with java script Now in my seconded container i want to load a different website example http://example.com

```
     <div class="page-container">     
        <div class="panel-container">       
            <div class="panel-left">            
            panel-left
            </div>
            <div class="splitter">
            </div>
            <div class="panel-right">
               I want to load a website here (http://example.com)
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
```

Comment: Then  what is `<iframe>` element for?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an iframe tag:

```
<iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
```